# Preventing rerenders when using object as state in useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Background:**

I am rendering a dynamic list of collapsible elements. The open/close state of the collapse is stored in a object as

```
 cosnt [collapse, setCollapse] = useState({a: false, b: false, c: false })
```

and this state is toggled with onClick with

```
const toggle = (id) => setCollapse({...collapse, [id]: !collapse[id]})
```

The collapse work but all the collapse elements are rerendered with each toggle, since, according to my understanding, a new object is created with every toggle which causes rerender of all the collapse elements. I want to only rerender the toggled collapse.

**Question:**

How can a toggle be done without causing other collapse elements to rerender?

**Example**

[image: Edit collapse-example]

It can be seen in the console that a single click causes all collapse elements to be rerendered.

Comment: Could you please show the returned JSX?

Comment: Please post a more complete example. Where you're defining Collapse, how you parent component looks like. It's really hard to guess

Comment: @Dupocas I have added a complete working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to prevent rerendering :

`React.memo()` : **for functional components**
Wrap the component with:

`React.memo(<Component />)`

This guarantees that it only rerenders if the prop changes. This is equivalent of a pure component.

---

`React.PureComponent()`: **for class components**
Same equivalent as above.

The other vanilla way for class components was by controlling the `shouldComponentUpdate` which should't be relied on for this case.

In your case, wrap with `React.memo` to avoid re-rendering.

Comment: Thanks! React.memo does prevent the the unnecessary rerender. Regarding why state changes? In my opnion, the setCollapse creates a new collapse state object with every toggle, therefore all the components using this state rerender regardless of having again the same value.

Comment: @MuhammadKamal Glad it worked. I misunderstood a part of your question. Kindly ignore. Updated the answer. pls mark as answer if it worked. CHeers!

Answer (score 0):

You are making the `Collapse` as a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), on click you making the parent render and therefore it doesn't work as you expect.

If you want to avoid rendering, you need to use the uncontrolled version or wrap it and compose it as uncontrolled.

Refer to [Controlled VS. Uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components) in React docs.

You have uncontrolled version in [`reactstrap`](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/) docs:

```
import React from 'react';
import { UncontrolledCollapse, Button, CardBody, Card } from 'reactstrap';

const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <Button color="primary" id="toggler" style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>
      Toggle
    </Button>
    <UncontrolledCollapse toggler="#toggler">
      <Card>
        <CardBody>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt magni, voluptas debitis
          similique porro a molestias consequuntur earum odio officiis natus, amet hic, iste sed
          dignissimos esse fuga! Minus, alias.
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </UncontrolledCollapse>
  </div>
);

export default Example;
```

Comment: But the Uncontrolled component works directly with the dom. Wouldn't it be better to use a component that uses react virtual dom as compared to directly manipulating the dom?

Comment: No... You skip a whole lifecycle of comparison in virtual dom